# How to remove an automatically generated canonical link from a product page using custom layout XML?

Tags: magento-1.9, layout

I already have canonical links turned on in my CE 1.9 install, but if I didn't I know that I can add a canonical link to a product using custom layout XML this way:

```
<reference name="head">
<action method="addLinkRel">
<rel>canonical</rel>
<href>https://www.example.html</href>
</action>
</reference>
```

I would like, however, to customize a particular product's canonical link and I would like to use custom XML to remove the original one before I add in the next so I don't have two links. Is this possible without modifying code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `/app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Html/Head.php` method `addLinkRel`:

```
     public function addLinkRel($rel, $href)
     {
        $this->addItem('link_rel', $href, 'rel="' . $rel . '"');
        return $this;
     }
```

it operating with `addItem` method, which operates with `$this->_data['items']` so you can basically use same way `removeItem` method in your xml :

```
    <action method="removeItem"><type>link_rel</type><href>https://www.example.html</href></action>
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work - except that if I do this: `<reference name="head">
<action method="removeItem">
 <type>link_rel</type>
<href>https://www.example.com/old.html</href>
</action>
</reference><reference name="head">
<action method="addLinkRel">
<rel>canonical</rel>
<href>https://www.example.com/new.html</href>
</action>
</reference>` then all that happens is the order in which the two canonical links are output changes - so that the new link appears before the old.  Odd.

Comment: try to remove unnecessary open/closing `</reference><reference name="head">` between actions. alos you can try  `setText` method as `<action method="setText"><text><![CDATA[<link rel="canonical" href="https://blog.example.com/dresses/green-dresses-are-awesome" />]]></text></action>`

Answer (score 8):

I have been trying to figure this out for quite a while now and none of the solutions I found worked. All I had to do to get it to work was to add another removeItem action with the same link but with **`?___SID=U`** added to the end.

The only reason I can think that this works is that the `removeItem` action is looking for the URL before the URL rewrite kicks in. Don't quote me on that though :)

```
<reference name="head">
   <action method="removeItem"><type>link_rel</type><href>{LINK}</href></action>
   <action method="removeItem"><type>link_rel</type><href>{LINK}?___SID=U</href></action>
   <action method="addLinkRel"><rel>canonical</rel><href>{LINK}</href></action>
</reference>
```